# calculus inquiry limits 1

Tags: calculus, limits

For f(x) to be continuous at x=2, the following 3 conditions must be met:

1- f(2) exists

2 - limx→2f(x) exists

3- limx→2f(x)=f(2)

Give a function of f (either with symbols or a graph) which satisfies the given combination of (1,2, and 3)

(a) 1 and 2 but not 3

(b) 1 but neither 2 or 3

(c) 2 but neither 1 or 3

(d) neither 1, 2, or 3

Comment: what problem are you having constructing the requisite functions?

Comment: @gt6989b i know that for part (d) an example of a function would be f(x)=x^2/x-2, but im just having difficulty finding a functions that work for parts a, b, and c

Comment: It’s not necessarily about finding so much as it is constructing.  As a hint, you can make piecewise functions...

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just a matter of thinking about what the question is asking.  The math is easy once you grasp that.

For part a), the function is defined, and the limit exists (conditions $1$ and $2$) but it has the "wrong value" at $2$ (condition $3.$)  So, take any continuous function and redefine it at $2.$  For example, $$f(x)=\cases{0, &$x\neq2$\\1,&$x=2$}$$

For part b), $f(2)$ is defined, but the limit doesn't exits.  Well, if the limit doesn't even exist, it clearly can't equal $f(2),$ so we get that condition $3$ fails for free.  We just need a function where the limit at $2$ doesn't exist, and then we can define $f(2)$ however we like.  I'll leave it to you to think of an example.

Once you've done part b), it should be easy to do part c).

Comment: what would be an example of a function where the limit at 2 doesnt exist for part b? would it be a piecewise function? @saulspatz

Comment: thank you so much for your help! i was totally lost. i tried doing it graphically but i was failing epically

Comment: When a question solves your problem, you should accept it with the check mark.  That way, it no longer shows up as unresolved.

Comment: @saulspatx what would be an example of a function where the limit at 2 doesnt exist for part b? would it be a piecewise function?

Comment: @A. Ferris Sure a jump discontinuity would work fine, but you could also have an infinite discontinuity like $\lim_{x\to0}{1\over x},$ or a oscillatory discontinuity like $\lim_{x\to0}\sin{1\over x}, $ for example.

Comment: f(x)=sin(1/x) and f(x)=1/x wouldnt work because the limit as x approaches 2 of those functions exist and that would satisfy part 2. Part b is that it meets the 1st condition but not the 2nd or 3rd condition. do you have an example of a function that does that im stuck

Comment: @A Ferris, I'm sorry, I was thinking the anomalous point was $x=0.$  You can just translate the behavior to $x=2,$ but I was just taking about your earlier question, "Would it be a piecewise function?"  All I meant was that there are other kinds of functions where the limit doesn't exist.  You could use $$f(x)=\cases{0, &$x<2$\\ 1,&$x\geq 2$}$$